# jQuery not:() - combing function

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've just written the following function and although it works - as in row colours are applied to all tables except those with the class .noAlternatingRows, due to .net not being able to apply a class directly to a table (no idea why - i'm not a .net developer, it's jut what i have been told) - i now need to remove table styling from tables that are nested within a span.

This works, however is there a way of combining the two together? I've tried to comma separate the elements which i do not want the styling applied to, but it doesn't seem to work...

```
  $("table:not(.noAlternatingRows, span table) tr:odd").css("background-color", "#d9d9d9");
    $("table:not(.noAlternatingRows, span table) tr:even").css("background-color", "#f2f2f2");
    $("span table tr:even").css("background", "none");
    $("span table tr:odd").css("background", "none");
```

I'm sure there's a neater way of writing it - thanks :)

Comment: Tried chaining the `:not` ? Like so:     `$("table:not(.noAlternatingRows):not(span table) tr:odd")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i now need to remove table styling from tables that are nested within a span

```
$('span tr').css("background", "none");
```

that's all folks ^^

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this selector:

```
$("table:not(.noAlternatingRows, span table) tr:odd")
```

Try this one:

```
$("table:not(.noAlternatingRows, span > table) tr:odd")
```

This will only select tables that are directly nested in a span, instead of being nested at an arbitrary depth. If this doesn't work could you provide a jsFiddle with a (not) working testcase?